# iOS: ViewController title reverts back to original

Tags: ios

I'm experiencing some issues with customizing the navigation bar items (title, custom bar buttons) for view controllers provided by iOS, such as ABPersonViewController and EKEventViewController, where my custom items disappear and the originals come back.

In the following example, I have a subclass of ABPersonViewController which has a custom title "My Title!":

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"My Title!";
}
```

[image]

The title appears as expected, but after interacting with this view controller for a while (such as clicking Edit to edit the contact info and pressing done, or even scrolling the view up and down multiple times) the title reverts back to the original "Info". How can I ensure that this doesn't happen?

This is happening on iOS 6.x and occurs with custom buttons I added on the navigation bar as well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would implement the view controller's `didReceiveMemoryWarning:` and add an `NSLog` in there to verify that the memory warning is actually causing your issue--in my experience this doesn't sound likely.

Comment: You are right-- not a memory issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `self.navigationItem.title` also in addition to what you are doing.

Comment: This by itself seems to do the trick. Still not sure why this is happening though, but many thanks!

Comment: When a view controller is pushed to navigation stack, UINavigationController will use the navigationItem title if present, otherwise only it will use the viewcontroller's title.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's causing it, but you could try setting the title later, like in `viewWillAppear:`.